# Hotkey causing variable to be unassigned?

Tags: autohotkey

I know I'm missing something obvious but I can't figure out why this doesn't work.  Why doesn't hello show up in the first msgbox I know it says the variable isn't assigned if I uncomment #Warn? This is the only thing in the ahk file.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

#SingleInstance force

; Reload the script  
^!z::
WinActivate, ahk_class Notepad++
Send {ctrl down}s{ctrl up}
sleep 100
Reload
return


ADPass = hello

!5::
MsgBox, %ADPass%
Msgbox, test
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assignment of `ADPass` never gets executed because it is between 2 hotkeys.  You must place it before you begin your hotkeys (before `^!z`) or place it within your hotkey (`!5`) to ensure it is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answer would probably work, you need the variable to be set before the return. The return means the machine is never getting to that line of code, Try this.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

#SingleInstance force
ADPass = hello; this doesn't have to stay here, just make sure it's before the return.
; Reload the script  
^!z::
WinActivate, ahk_class Notepad++
Send {ctrl down}s{ctrl up}
sleep 100
Reload
return




!5::
MsgBox, %ADPass%
Msgbox, test
return
```

or

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

#SingleInstance force
; Reload the script  
^!z::
WinActivate, ahk_class Notepad++
Send {ctrl down}s{ctrl up}
sleep 100
Reload
return




!5::
goto set
point:
MsgBox, %ADPass%
Msgbox, test
return


set:
ADPass = hello
goto point
Return
```